# Ownership of records shared using salesforce to salesforce

Tags: integration, salesforce-to-salesforce

I am currently experimenting with Salesforce-to-salesforce. I have successfully shared record using S2S.
when I view the shared record in destination org.
Created By is - Connection User
Last Modified By is - Connection User
This is as expected and I understand what this is.

But the Owner of this shared record is System Admin of destination org.

I have connected two sandbox environments using S2S and we have multiple admins.
Admin1 shared record from source org and in the destination org shared record has owner id as Admin2.

Can someone explain how the ownership of record shared using S2S works ?
Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Comment: do you have any workflows or triggers in destination org that change the owner?  Last time I used S2S, the default owner was `Connection User` but we had a workflow that changed the owner based on other fields in the shared SObject.

Comment: @crop1645 No. There is no workflow or trigger that is changing the owner.